# Spark: Save Dataframe in ORC format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, orc

In the previous version, we used to have a 'saveAsOrcFile()' method on RDD. This is now gone! How do I save data in DataFrame in ORC File format?

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
println("Creating Orc File!")
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("orcfile")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

val people = sc.textFile("/apps/testdata/people.txt")
val schemaString = "name age"
val schema = StructType(schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName => {if(fieldName == "name") StructField(fieldName, StringType, true) else StructField(fieldName, IntegerType, true)}))
val rowRDD = people.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Row(p(0), new Integer(p(1).trim)))

//# Infer table schema from RDD**
val peopleSchemaRDD = hiveContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)

//# Create a table from schema**
peopleSchemaRDD.registerTempTable("people")
val results = hiveContext.sql("SELECT * FROM people")
results.map(t => "Name: " + t.toString).collect().foreach(println)

// Now I want to save this Dataframe(peopleSchemaRDD) in ORC Format. How do I do that?
```

}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since  Spark 1.4 you can simply use `DataFrameWriter` and set `format` to `orc`:

```
peopleSchemaRDD.write.format("orc").save("people")
```

or

```
peopleSchemaRDD.write.orc("people")
```